# Why are there no WS-Security/WS-Policy declarations in the Amazon EC2 WSDL?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ws-security

The [AWS EC2 SOAP API documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-soap-api.html#using-soap-api-wsdl)  discusses securing the SOAP message using the WS-Security standard (specifically the X509 token profile).

However, [the WSDL linked from the page](http://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads/ec2.wsdl) doesn't have any WS-Security/WS-Policy declarations.  What am I missing?  Is the requirement to use X509 meant to be conveyed completely out-of-band through this documentation?  That seems odd.  I noticed that the WSDL was updated 2012-06-01 - is it possible that the WS-Security requirement has been relaxed?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to request a certificate for SOAP operations under your Amazon account. It will provide two files (private key and cert, both are PEM files).

Follow this [link](https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials), login if needed and take a look into the "Access Credentials
" section. There's a "X.509 Certificates" tab, where you can download existing certificates or create a new one.